# jQuery replaced \n with <br> HTML does not render <br>

Tags: html

I have managed to replace all `\n` with `<br>` from my postgresql db. I need a TextAreaField to show linebreaks.

The problem is, the text is replaced but all `<br>` are not rendered as HTML elements:

[image]

That is how I replace:

```
$('.js-make-please-br').text($('.js-make-please-br').text().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
```

In HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using jQuery's `.html()` method to set the contents instead: http://api.jquery.com/html/

**Solution:**

Change the first `text()` to `html()`

```
$('.js-make-please-br').html($('.js-make-please-br').text().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
```

Comment: Works, thanks. Had to change the first text() to html() will accept in 5 min

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Could you accept my answer if that fixed it?